# Dialogflow Slots Via Mutiple Call

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-api-nodejs-client

In Dialogflow Agent I've one of the intents with multiple slots and all of them are required. It's not possible to provide information for all the slots at once.

e.g.

I've an intent with three slot :
i) Email
ii) Phone
iii)Date of Birth(DOB)

The way i want it to work is ask for email , user's provides an Email , then ask for phone and then DOB. I'm using Dialogflow NodeJS Client API to make request to Agent.

As of now when i make the first request(passing query/utterance) to detect the intent , it detects the intent , now when I pass the value the slot it goes to default fallback.

Also , using webhook for slot filling is not an option for me as the agent is going to be invoked by the client api.

I tried using events instead of queryText but couldn't get it working either.

Comment: There is an example in the documentation that I understand is what you want. Have you followed https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters#required?

Comment: Yes I've followed this , but this is pretty baisc example and doesn't work in my use case.

Comment: Are you passing Session id correctly? 
Could post a snippet of the code you use to make the calls? 
Have you raised an issue in the Node.js library?

Answer (score 1):

Found the Answer, Initially i was the sample code provide with the Dialogflow library([Dialogflow NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/dialogflow) ). The problem was for every request a new sessionId was generated , when sessionId was same the slots were filled.

So instead of using the UUID to generate a sessionId for every request , i'm passing the sessionId along with the query to form the request body.